# Accessing SharePoint sites using Graph API

Tags: .net, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to upload file to SharePoint site using background service, so far I can't even succeed with listing sites. I believe there is an issue with permissions/access on my side, below is core code I am using:

```
var application = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create("APP_ID")
    .WithClientSecret("APP_SECRET")
    .WithTenantId("TENANT_GUID")
    .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(application, "https://*****.sharepoint.com/.default");
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var sites = await graphClient.Sites.Request().GetAsync();
```

But in this case exception thrown:

```
Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.
```

If I remove scope from ClientCredentialProvider, next exception will come:

```
Code: AccessDenied Message: Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.
```

Application itself has all required permissions:
[image]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here

Comment: You need to give the scope link as `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` because you are using Graph SDK and please add the Application permissions `Sites.ReadWrite.All` under the MicrosoftGraph Permissions but not under the Sharepoint Permission. Give it a try and let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thank, that did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(clientId)
        .WithTenantId(tenantID)
        .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
        .Build();
    
    ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

    GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
    //To access the root SharePoint site：
    var site1 = await graphClient.Sites["root"]
               .Request()
               .GetAsync();
    //To access the Specified SharePoint site：
    var site2 = await graphClient.Sites["{site-id}"]
               .Request()
               .GetAsync();
```

And as @Shiva- MSFT Identity said, please add the Application permissions `Sites.ReadWrite.All` under the MicrosoftGraph Permissions but not under the Sharepoint Permission.

Answer (score 0):

My test code for your reference:

```
string clientID = "cde921c5-abcd-abcd-a450-6dabcd46fec5"; // Put the Application ID from above here.
            string clientSecret = "N7b1sxnxGCxLLWx9m0~UJUxBx.PNGrqb.K"; // Put the Client Secret from above here.

            string graphApiResource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
            Uri microsoftLogin = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/");
            string tenantID = "2e83cc45-652e-418b-a85v-80c281v30c09"; // Put the Azure AD Tenant ID from above here.

            // The authority to ask for a token: your azure active directory.
            string authority = new Uri(microsoftLogin, tenantID).AbsoluteUri;
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientID, clientSecret);

            // Picks up the bearer token.
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphApiResource, clientCredential).Result;

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                async (requestMessage) =>
                {
                    // This is adding a bearer token to the httpclient used in the requests.
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);
                }));
            
            var sites =  graphClient.Sites.Request().GetAsync();
```